# How to create a RenderURL during action phase in a portlet?

Tags: liferay, portlet, liferay-6

In the method `processAction(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response)`, I  insert a record into database and get the `ID` and then
I want to redirect to the view page of this record. So I need to create a `RenderURL` with a parameter value for that ID.

`ActionResponse` doesn't provide method to create a `renderURL`. Some codes in Liferay do similar things like:

1. create `renderURL` before accessing the `actionURL`
2. pass the `renderURL` as a parameter in the `actionURL`

However, at that time, I don't know the value of `ID`.

Other codes also use `new PortletURLImpl()` directly. My portlet cannot see that class.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't say it clearly. I want the `renderURL` as an redirect URL. If you don't redirect, when you refresh or press enter in the address bar, you'll get wrong page result.

Answer (score 2):

> Other codes also use new PortletURLImpl() directly. My portlet cannot see that class.

Because this class is in `portal-impl.jar` and also it is not recommended to use classes from this jar. Starting from Liferay 6.1, you won't be able to build your portlet from plugins-sdk if you classes point to `portal-impl.jar`.

Now to answer your question:

Any jsp is rendered by the `render` method or [`doView`](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs-all/com/liferay/util/bridges/mvc/MVCPortlet.html#doView%28javax.portlet.RenderRequest,%20javax.portlet.RenderResponse%29) method (if using liferay's [`MVCPortlet`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.x/util-bridges/src/com/liferay/util/bridges/mvc/MVCPortlet.java)) and this method would be called as part of the normal life-cycle of portlets.

Here are the steps you would need to take:

1. set a render parameter (using [response.setRenderParameter()](http://www.bluesunrise.com/portlet-api/javax/portlet/StateAwareResponse.html#setRenderParameter%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method) in your `processAction' method at the last which would be available in your render method, as follows:

   ```
   actionResponse.setRenderParameter("myID", 1201);
   ```

   <sub>**Just for info:** After using `setRenderParameter` you cannot use [`sendRedirect`](http://portals.apache.org/pluto/portlet-2.0-apidocs/javax/portlet/ActionResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29) method</sub>
2. fetch this `"myID"` in your render method as you fetch any other request parameter:

   ```
   //assuming your ID is a long
   long myUserName = ParamUtil.getLong(renderRequest, "myID");
   ```

   or

   ```
   String strMyID = renderRequest.getParameter("myID");
   long myID = Long.parseLong(strMyID);
   ```
3. After this, just use

   ```
   include(renderPage, renderRequest, renderResponse);
   ```

   were `renderPage` is nothing but a string containing the path to your jsp within `docroot` like `/html/yourportlet/view.jsp`

   <sub>**Just as an afterthought:**

   If you are using a Liferay IDE, then you can try creating a simple portlet project with `MVCPortlet` and then look at the generated `portlet.xml`'s `<init-param>`</sub>

So basically you need to pass information from action-phase to render-phase, the [development guide](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/passing-information-from-the-action-phase-to-the-render-pha-4) is a good place for explaining this in detail.

That's it.
Hope this helps.

Let me know if you have any confusion regarding this.

Comment: Thank you, Prakash. I tried your way. After actionURL, you cannot refresh or press enter in the address bar.

Comment: BTW, in some cases, `PortalUtil.copyRequestParameters` would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

In action phase do the following:

```
ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay)request.getAttribute (WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
PortletURL url = PortletURLFactoryUtil.create(request, this.getPortletName(), themeDisplay.getPlid(), PortletRequest.RENDER_PHASE);
```

For example, if you want to redirect to the login page and back, you can do the following:

```
response.sendRedirect("/c/portal/login?redirect=" + HttpUtil.encodeURL(url.toString()));
```

Definitely you can add or copy the parameters as required.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating the renderURL you can include the view page include(viewTemplate,actionRequest,actionResponse). Or if you want to sent any parameter any want's to get it in doView then use actionResponse.setParameter(name,value) method

Answer (score -1):

I create a `RenderURL` with a place holder as parameter value, like this:

```
   <portlet:renderURL var="redirect">
      <portlet:param name="ID" value="__ID__" />
   </portlet:renderURL>`
```

In `processAction`:

```
    String redirect = redirectParam.replace("__ID__", "123213");
    actionResponse.sendRedirect(redirect) ;
```